# Python sounddevice example doesnt emit any sound (raspberry pi)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Hi i was trying to start working with the python sounddevice module and therefore i started with the example "Play sine" of the sounddevice documentation https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.14/examples.html

Unfortunately I dont get any sound from my raspberry pi. I have installed the necessary libraries. Does anybody know what the reason could be?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you attached speakers or headphones? How?

Comment: I have tried both: headphones via audio jack and a monitor via hdmi, but no sound.